# Order Data based on previous row data

Tags: sql, oracle, sorting

I have a query in Oracle SQL. My query gives three columns: `old_data` ,`new_data` and `transaction_date`. I want to sort this data primarily based on increasing `transaction_date` and secondly in such a way that `new_data` of previous row equals `old_data` of next row. Both `new_data` and `old_date` are number fields that can decrease or increase.

If I sort just by `transaction_date`, some data has the same exact date and time and hence the order will not be accurate as I need `new_data` of previous row to match `old_data` of current row. I also cannot use a hierarchical query alone to meet the second sorting condition since `transaction_date` sorting is the primary sorting condition.

Can anyone suggest a solution?

A sample output will need to look like below:
[output_sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuKGS.png)

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Lag()](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions070.htm) window function may help you here and a case expression.  use the case expression to look back a row to determine if the column value matches the lag column's value.  and then you an use the result in your ordering  However, you may have a problem if old/new data could match on more than 1 value with the same transation date...

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statement for your table; the `INSERT` statement for some sample data; a detailed explanation of the logic you want to implement (including how you pick the first row in each group of equal dates); and the expected output for that sample data.

Comment: Based on your sample data, just order by the old_data column and the timestamp column will naturally be in the order you want. *(So, please improve your sample data to demonstrate your full requirement.)* Also; [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a hierarchical query and connect by equal dates as well as the relationship between old- and new-data:

```sql
SELECT transaction_date,
       new_data,
       old_data
FROM   table_name
START WITH old_data IS NULL -- You need to define how to pick the first row
CONNECT BY
       PRIOR transaction_date = transaction_date
AND    PRIOR new_data = old_date
ORDER SIBLINGS BY
       transaction_date
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';
```

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( transaction_date, new_data, old_data ) AS
SELECT DATE '2022-01-01', 1, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-01-01', 2, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-01-01', 3, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-01-02', 3, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-01-02', 1, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-01-02', 2, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2022-01-03', 4, NULL FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| TRANSACTION_DATE | NEW_DATA | OLD_DATA |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | 1 | *null* |
| 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | 2 | 1 |
| 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | 3 | 2 |
| 2022-01-02 00:00:00 | 3 | *null* |
| 2022-01-02 00:00:00 | 1 | 3 |
| 2022-01-02 00:00:00 | 2 | 1 |
| 2022-01-03 00:00:00 | 4 | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/bUxZLREr)

---

#### Update

Given the updated sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( transaction_date, old_data, new_data ) AS
SELECT DATE '2021-12-20'+INTERVAL '11:25' HOUR TO MINUTE,   0,       115.09903 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-12-20'+INTERVAL '11:25' HOUR TO MINUTE, 115.09903, 115.13233 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-12-20'+INTERVAL '11:25' HOUR TO MINUTE, 115.13233, 115.16490 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-12-20'+INTERVAL '11:25' HOUR TO MINUTE, 115.16490, 115.19678 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-12-20'+INTERVAL '11:35' HOUR TO MINUTE, 115.19678, 115.22799 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-12-20'+INTERVAL '11:35' HOUR TO MINUTE, 115.22799, 115.25854 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-12-20'+INTERVAL '11:35' HOUR TO MINUTE, 115.25854, 115.28846 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-12-20'+INTERVAL '11:35' HOUR TO MINUTE, 115.28846, 115.31776 FROM DUAL;
```

Then, since both `old_data` and `new_data` increase with time, you could use:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
ORDER BY old_data;
```

or:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
ORDER BY new_data;
```

or, if you want to use the hierarchy then:

```sql
SELECT transaction_date,
       old_data,
       new_data
FROM   table_name
START WITH old_data = 0
CONNECT BY
       PRIOR transaction_date <= transaction_date
AND    PRIOR new_data = old_data
ORDER SIBLINGS BY
       transaction_date
```

Which all output:

| TRANSACTION_DATE | OLD_DATA | NEW_DATA |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-12-20 11:25:00 | 0 | 115.09903 |
| 2021-12-20 11:25:00 | 115.09903 | 115.13233 |
| 2021-12-20 11:25:00 | 115.13233 | 115.1649 |
| 2021-12-20 11:25:00 | 115.1649 | 115.19678 |
| 2021-12-20 11:35:00 | 115.19678 | 115.22799 |
| 2021-12-20 11:35:00 | 115.22799 | 115.25854 |
| 2021-12-20 11:35:00 | 115.25854 | 115.28846 |
| 2021-12-20 11:35:00 | 115.28846 | 115.31776 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/use8hvw2)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. This solution partially works except that my old_data is continuous. First value for old_data is 0. So in your example given, the old_data for Jan-2nd will also have some data. So it means PRIOR transaction_date = transaction_date will not work. Sorry if I wasn't clearer in my question.